# Which algorithm would be appropriate for situation analysis?

Tags: android, algorithm, data-structures

I am developing an android application for analyzing the situation of user based on sensor values and other details. The app is basically a reminder with features which helps user based on his situation.

We provide the app our daily routine as events with location and necessary details. When the time of event reached, it analyses the user's current situation before notifying by reading his location, time, weather, accelerator moving or not (ie busy or not) , phone is in pocket or not, distance from destination of event, time it would take to reach there etc.

It then chooses a set of actions that might be helpful before reaching the destination like read the news , provide navigation, open media player, show stock details, perform search etc. An algorithm should pick these actions from a set of actions.

Which algorithm and data structure would be appropriate for analyzing the current situation??
Please provide your views on the project and idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

2 approaches come to mind:

1. Insert into a hash table all of your possible actions when the key is the set of various data elements. I.e., `h({data1, data2,...}) = a1; h({dataa, datab,...}) = a2`. Whenever the time comes, apply the hash function on the dataset and extract the action.
2. The problem with 1 is the possible size of the hash, which will have to include all the possible combinations of values - the size will be `num of sensor1 values * num of sensor2 values * ... * num of sensor n values`. If action on every combination is different, there is nothing to optimize. But it's probably not the case and in most cases the actions will be the same. You can take the opposite approach and save the set of all possible actions in a map, for example. At a very high level: whenever time of event arrives, start analyzing the data - after reading the first sensor data, the set of possible actions will shrink; analyze the second sensor data and repeat the process for the subset of actions. Continue until only single action remains or no more sensor data available, whatever comes first (assuming all combinations of sensor data are mapped to a valid action).

Answer (score 1):

When reading about your project logic and especially horn clauses came into my mind. You describe, that your app should check a set of conditions to select a certain action to perform. [Horn clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) are a certain form of logical expressions in [propositional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) or [first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). Horn clauses have at most one positive literals and express either a fact, a rule or a goal. With the facts it is possible to describe your knowledge, with the rules you can express which action to choose if certain conditions apply. Horn clauses, first-order logic, propositional logic and resolution are the theoretical foundation for logic programming, rules engines or constrained satisfaction.

E.g. [drools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drools) is a rules engine which allows to describe a knowledge base and a set of rules. Drools uses first-order inference to reason actions from the knowledge base and the conditions of the rules. Maybe, you will find something which you can use in the area of first-order logic, propositional logic, rules engines, logic, programming, constrained satisfaction, inference, problem solving and reasoning. You may find there for example the  [rete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) used in drools.